# Azure database for MySQL resource is not appearing in resource list in azure portal even when the application using it is working fine

Tags: azure, azure-database-mysql

I have a azure database for MySQL, it was created last month. Application using it is working fine but when I logged into Azure Portal to add some firewall rules I can't see the db on the resource list. It appears in billing section to show the cost but nowhere else and I am unable to add network firewall rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I raised a support ticket with Microsoft Azure Team and they resolved it for me. Posting below a response from one of the team members:

We just fixed the issue, please try to browse Azure Portal you should be able to see the server.

This is a known issue due to a issue in the layer of communication with ARM, and the server disappear but will be available for connection.

Please verify and let me know if you need any further assistance from our side.

Looking forward to hearing from you.

Thank you!

Comment: How did you raise the support ticket? We have the same issue but have a basic support plan so they don't let us create a technical support ticket anyway

Comment: We also have basic support plan, I also got confused here but then raised a normal ticket under this category: Azure/Subscription management/Unable to access my subscription/Issues signing in or accessing my subscriptions

Answer (score 0):

Did you create this database or did someone else create it for you?

There are a couple of things it could be:

1. You might not have permissions on the Azure Database for MySQL resource itself, so you can't see it
2. You might have a filter on your list view; where exactly are you looking for the resource? Is it from the 'Azure Database for MySQL Servers' blade? Or the 'All Resources' blade?
3. Are you in the correct subscription? I assume so, as you say you can see it in the cost view, but worth double checking.

Those are a few things that come to mind as to why you can't see it, but don't really have enough detail to give a definitive answer.

Comment: Thank you Anthony for your response, I was the one who created and could see it as I have added firewall rules few weeks ago so I don't think there is any permission issue. It just suddenly disappeared. I am checking it in all resource list and there are no filters I double checked. I checked in Azure Database for MySQL blade as well and nothing, I am assuming as I can create new one right now then there should not be any issue with permission or subscription.

Comment: Do you have access to multiple subscriptions? In the All Resource list can you see other resources you expect to see in the same subscription as the MySQL Server? Does anyone else have the necessary access to modify your permissions? Can you see the resource group that the MySQL Server was created in?

Comment: I have only one subscription and it is the main account. I can see the resource group and all other resources. One of my azure app service is connected to this database and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: If you can do so without revealing any sensitive information, can you add a screenshot to your post of the Azure Database for MySQL Servers blade? I'm curious to see what you see.

If you use Azure Powershell or Azure CLI, can you see it?

CLI: ```az mysql server list```
Powershell: ```Get-AzMySqlServer```

Comment: I tried CLI with command az mysql server list, it came back empty. In Azure Database for MySQL Servers blade there is nothing, it just says No servers to display and create button for creating new. I have raised a support ticket with Microsoft customer support team now because this is very weird. I will post it here when I get an answer from them.